# Tag If in template django

Tags: python, django

Working code:

```
  {% if request.user.manager.position != 'E' %}
      {% endif %}
```

models.py

```
Position_choices = (('M', u'Manager'), ('E', u'Staff'), ('U', u'Other_staff'))
class Manager(models.Model):
...
    position = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Position_choices, default='M')
```

models.py for proj

```
class Project(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, blank=True, null=True, related_name='manager_set')
    Other_staff = models.ForeignKey(Manager, blank=True, null=True, related_name='staff_set')
    Staff= models.ForeignKey(Manager, blank=True, null=True, related_name='otherstaff_set')
```

I'm displaying some blocks on the page html, depending on staff position. But in the past there was only one staff, but now they are 2. I try:

```
 {% if request.user.manager.position in ['E', 'U'] %}
```

result:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['E',' from '['E','
```

Could you help with correct query, please.

Answer (score 3):

Django templates doesn't support list literals, I would say easiest way is to pass your list `['E', 'U']` as variable and later do:

```
{% if request.user.manager.position in allowed_positions %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Relevant previous question: [Checking if something exists in items of list variable in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054189/checking-if-something-exists-in-items-of-list-variable-in-django-template)

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Create the choice list in the Python backend and pass it through the context to do the comparison:

> {% if request.user.manager.position in request.positive_list %}

2. Split the condition with an OR:

> ```
> {% if request.user.manager.position == 'E' | request.user.manager.position == 'U' %}
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try sending the list with valids positions to template as a variable. You can't 'define' a list directly in template.