# python check two values to be between two values

Tags: python, numbers

I have an issue, I want to verify if two values are between two values like:

```
val1 = 23.04
val2 = 29.04

tobe1 = 24.04
tobe2 = 27.04
if tobe1, tobe2 in range(val1, val2):
   print("something")
```

Comment: Range lets you iterate over values. So `range(val1, val2)` makes an sequence of values between `val1` and `val2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should get you the required result

```py
val1 = 23.04
val2 = 29.04

tobe1 = 24.04
tobe2 = 27.04

your_list = [tobe1, tobe2]
if all(val1 < x < val2 for x in (tobe1, tobe2)):
    print("something")
```

If you want ALL values in (tobe1, tobe2) to be within the val1 and val2, then use `all`

If you want ANY value in (tobe1, tobe2) to be within the val1 and val2, then use `any`.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly for what I want to do, if you know something about this did you have any idea how I can use this code in django template?

Comment: You should be only using simple logic in django templates. If your logic is complex, you should be doing it in your `views`. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054189/checking-if-something-exists-in-items-of-list-variable-in-django-template) talks about using list comprehensions in Django templates, and should help you

Comment: {% for d in luna %}
                                <td class="text-center">
                                        {% if d.0 > i.5 > d.1%}
                                            {{ i.4 }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                </td>
                            {% endfor %}

Comment: this is my actual django template code, and I want to use your code that you give me above

Comment: `d` is the loop index. Not sure what `i` is in your code

Comment: {% for i in concedii %} {% endfor %} all of that is inside another loop

Comment: It's difficult to get the complete picture from code snippets. You might have to post another question by narrowing down your views and template logic in another question

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> 3 < 5
True
>>> 3 < 4 < 6
True
>>> 3 < 7 < 6
False
```

`range()` method does something different than you expect. Use simple `<` comparators. You can replace my example values with variables.